# Strip all reluctant curly braces using regex

Tags: java, regex

Note: This is a **Java**-only question (i.e. no Javascript, sed, Perl, etc.)

I need to filter out all the "reluctant" curly braces (`{}`) in a long string of text.

(by "reluctant" I mean as in [reluctant quantifier](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)).

I have been able to come up with the following regex which correctly finds and lists all such occurrences:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\{)(.*?)(\\})", Pattern.DOTALL);  
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(originalString);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        Log.d("WITHIN_BRACES", matcher.group(2));
    }
```

My problem now is how to replace *every* found `matcher.group(0)` with the **corresponding** `matcher.group(2)`.

Intuitively I tried:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
  String noBraces = matcher.replaceAll(matcher.group(2));           
}
```

But that replaced all found `matcher.group(0)` with only the *first* `matcher.group(2)`, which is of course not what I want.

Is there an expression or a method in Java's regex to perform this "corresponding replaceAll" that I need?

**ANSWER:** Thanks to the tip below, I have been able to come up with 2 fixes that did the trick:

```
if (matcher.find()) {
  String noBraces = matcher.replaceAll("$2");           
}
```

1. Fix #1: Use `"$2"` instead of `matcher.group(2)`
2. Fix #2: Use `if` instead of `while`.

Works now like a charm.

Comment: please provide some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the special backreference syntax:

`String noBraces = matcher.replaceAll("$2");`

Comment: Oh, now I see. You are using `while(matcher.find())` twice in a row! That's why your second loop does nothing - the matcher is already done matching. You have to do all work in one `while` loop.

Comment: @Kilian Foth Actually, I am *not* using `while(matcher.find())` twice in a row at all. But I *am* using `while()` -- to iterate through all found `matcher.group(2)`s. Are you saying that I should not `while()` at all? I am going to try that now...

Comment: @Kilian Foth Replacing `while()` with `if()` did the trick. This is so confusing... To clarify: `"$2"` works, whereas `matcher.group(2)` **doesn't** work.