# What is the difference between matcher.group(N) and "$N"

Tags: java, regex

Earlier today I was surprised to realize that `matcher.replaceAll("$2")` works whereas `matcher.replaceAll(matcher.group(2))` **doesn't** work ([as intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308634/strip-all-reluctant-curly-braces-using-regex/7308776#7308776)).

I thought that both refer to the same thing: The string matched by the pair of capturing parentheses.

Apparently, there is a subtle difference about which I couldn't find detailed enough documentation.

I found [this excellent intro/tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html) referring to both but it failed short of delving deeper into the subtle difference.

Where can I find more information about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From API documentation of [Matcher.replaceAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29):

> This method first resets this matcher. It then scans the input
>   sequence looking for matches of the pattern. Characters that are not
>   part of any match are appended directly to the result string; each
>   match is replaced in the result by the replacement string. The
>   replacement string may contain references to captured subsequences as
>   in the appendReplacement method.

This means that `$2` will take the value of second group each time a match is found.

On the other hand when you use Matcher.group(2) you use it only once - so replaceAll() takes just plain String with second group from the first match that was found by `find()` method.

Comment: "...from the **first** match" -- is the key. This is indeed what I have observed. The question now is where is this documented? Thanks +1.

Comment: It is not documented, because it cannot be in any other way: you by yourself call group(2) only once, it returns a String (for example, "123") and it is given as argument: replaceAll("123"). replaceAll() inside doesn't even know that you've taken this string from some match.

Comment: OK. I understand that replaceAll() doesn't know that I am taking the replacement string from `group(2)`, but how does one conclude from `"The replacement string may contain references to captured subsequences as in the appendReplacement method"` that `This means that $2 will take the value of second group each time a match is found`? What am I missing? Thanks +1.

Comment: Hm, `replaceAll()` consequently finds matches (for example via `find()`). Each match has its own matched groups one can reference with $n. This means that $2 for each in match will refer to 2nd group in this match. I don't quite get what way is alternative. Do you mean that "$2" in your example could work as group(2) (i.e. refer only to group in first match)? But in this way we couldn't achieve behavior that gives us "$2" by other means (at least in such easy way).

Comment: You certainly provided more insight about this and so I will accept your answer shortly. I wish the formal documentation would have been clearer on this. I had to go through debug in order to learn the difference and I usually prefer to know up front what to expect. I guess this is what's called experience. +1. :)

Comment: @uTubeFan: Note that in Java 7 you can give your capture groups names.